# How to indent/outdent text with spaces or tabs in TinyMCE 4?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any plugin or did anyone already achieved this with custom implementation?

Answer (score 2):

what you need is the nonbreaking plugin:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/nonbreaking/

also use the "nonbreaking_force_tab" option

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. This just replaces selection with spaces, does not indent it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZoyNQ?editors=1010 This is easily done using `editor.insertContent('&nbsp;&nbsp;');`. No need for plugins to do that, basically it's also what `nonbreaking` actually does.